How to mount userdata while in recovery?
My Sony Xperia 1 V is using an unofficial build of LineageOS (rooted with Magisk) and after a few weeks of working fine, became stuck in a bootloop. I can access Fastboot and Recovery fine, and I still have the PIN and all my fingers (enrolled for fingerprints). LineageOS's Recovery also allows me to start a root shell via ADB from a PC connected with a USB cable.
How can I recover my data from the userdata partition? Can it be mounted while in recovery? If not, how can I make use of my ability to mount the system partition (also in read-write) and sideload things in Recovery to add some software that would allow me to back up my userdata (before attempting a fix to get rid of the bootloop)?

The question is not if you can mount user data but if the recovery supports decryption of user data (should be FBE). From what I remember the LineageOS Recovery ROMs can not compare to TWRP, especially user data decryption was only available for the latter (for some devices). Therefore I would try find a TWRP version for your device.

https://xdaforums.com/t/recovery-unofficial-updated-teamwin-recovery-project-3-7-1-for-xperia-1v-03-20-2024.4662645

As @Robert and @alecxs mentioned in the comments, the solution is to upload TWRP instead of LineageOS Recovery, which asks for the PIN and decrypts data straight away. It can then be backed up using TWRP's Backup feature, or accessed directly via ADB.
